# See http transactions in order to simulate programmatically

Tags: http, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to login to a website and I need to see the HTTP transactions when I log in by browser then simulate procedure by my application in java using Apache Httpclient.

Are there any tools or software for this? If there are any, where can I download them?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Google Chrome as your browser, this is a feature in [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)

Simple press <kbd>F12</kbd> and switch to the Network tab. Here you can get headers and content of HTTP requests. You can also right click the HTTP request and get it as cURL (cmd or bash)

[image]

You can combine this with the Chrome extension [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) which can help you generate the code for a number of programming languages (including Java OK HTTP and Java Unirest).

Comment: Can i get every thing that i need to simulate with this feature?

Comment: You should be able to get the required headers along with the needed data and HTTP request type, so you should be able to simulate it